# Moving master InfoPath Form locations and publishing to SharePoint

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-library

I've created several forms for our team SharePoint site and once in the past I did a "Save As" and then published and the newly published form deleted all of my old data.

I have a new form that I have built and maintained. I'm moving job roles therefore transferring the maintenance of this form from myself to another individual. The original master form that I designed, and was first published from, sits on my hard drive. When I moved this to her computer, prior to publishing it asked her to do a "Save As". How do I move master InfoPath Form Files to be publishable through an existing data connection without losing legacy forms?